# Criar textboxes em tempo de execução

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, button

Tenho um projeto que, basicamente, é um programa que calcula o consumo de energia elétrica de vários equipamentos que estou criando no VS2013.

O problema é que como não quero botar apenas um equipamento ou uma quantidade limitada, quero que tenha um botão que toda vez que o usuário clique nele, adicione 2 novas `textboxes` (Watts consumidos pelo equipamento e quantidade de horas por dia que ele fica ligado), porém não tenho nenhuma ideia de como fazer isso.

E se possível, também um botão que apareça ao lado das novas `textboxes` que exclua ela.

EDIT: Segue o código que fiz (É bastante simples)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        ConsumoDiario = 0.0;
        ConsumoMensal = 0.0;
        Ultimonumero = 0.0;
        Horas = 0.0;
        InitializeComponent();
        mtbconsumo.Text = "0";
        mtbhrs.Text = "0";
    }

    private void Calcular(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mtbconsumo.Text == "")
            Ultimonumero = 0;
        else
            Ultimonumero = Convert.ToDouble(mtbconsumo.Text);
        if (mtbhrs.Text == "" )
            Horas = 0;
        else
        Horas = Convert.ToInt32(mtbhrs.Text);

        ConsumoDiario = (Ultimonumero * Horas) / 1000;
        ConsumoMensal = ConsumoDiario * 30;
        mtbConsumoD.Text = Convert.ToString(ConsumoDiario);
        mtbConsumoM.Text = Convert.ToString(ConsumoMensal);
    }

}
```

Comment: WinForms ou WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta do @Randrade responde perfeitamente a sua pergunta. Como eu já tinha começado a escrever um exemplo, vou deixar aqui a minha dica:

A abordagem que uso é bem parecida com a apresentada na outra resposta.

Primeiramente, adicionei um `panel` ao form e defini a propriedade `AutoScroll` como `true`, para que, seja possível adicionar quantos TextBoxes sejam necessários e que isso não acabe estragando os outros componentes no form.

Aqui está o código utilizado para criar os componentes, é tudo muito simples, não há mistério nenhum.

```
private const int TextBoxX = 5;                //Posição horizontal do textbox no painel
private const int TextBoxWidth = 300;          //Largura do textbox
private const int ButtonX = TextBoxWidth + 10; //Posição horizontal do button no painel
private int _controlY = 5;                     //Posição vertical dos controles

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]
    {
        new TextBox
        {
            Location = new Point(TextBoxX, _controlY),
            Size = new Size(300, 20)
        },

        new Button
        {
            Text = "Texto",
            Location = new Point(ButtonX, _controlY),
            Size = new Size(100, 20)
        }
    });

    _controlY += 25;
}
```

Comment: Bem mais limpa. :p +1

Comment: É o "amado" costume com winforms ***=)***

Answer (score 3):

Se estiver utilizando `WinForms`, basta fazer desta forma:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Contador de botões para definir posição e demais propriedades
        int contador = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Função chamada ao click do botão
            AddNewTextBox();
        }

        public void AddNewTextBox()
        {
            //Define posição top
            var top = contador * 25;

            //Novo textBox watts
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Top = top;
            txt.Left = 10;
            txt.Text = "Watts  " + this.contador.ToString();
            txt.Name = "watts" + contador;
            //Adiciona no Form
            this.Controls.Add(txt);

            //Novo textBox Consumo
            TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
            txt1.Top = top;
            txt1.Left = 110;
            txt1.Text = "Consumo  " + this.contador.ToString();
            txt1.Name = "consumo" + contador;
            //Adiciona no Form
            this.Controls.Add(txt1);

            //Incrementa Contador
            contador = contador + 1;
        }
    }
```

Neste código nós temos um contador que ajuda a definir o layout dos campos adicionados, ou seja, mudando posição para um não sobrescrever o outro.

Ao clicar no botão, a função `AddNewTextBox()` é chamada, e ela é a responsável por adicionar os dois `TextBox()` no `Form`. Nota que o contador também serve para alterar o `Name` e o `Text`de cada `TextBox()`.

Vale ressaltar que a função está adicionando `TextBox()`, mas pode ser adicionado qualquer elemento ao `Form` ou à outro elemento, como um `Panel` por exemplo.

Fonte: [How to create Dynamic Controls in C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/dynamic-controls-cs.htm)

#### Edição

Conforme o comentário do [@jbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137363/criar-textboxes-em-tempo-de-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o/137374?noredirect=1#comment284755_137374), vale ressaltar que o código acima não verifica o tamanho do form, ou seja, ele adiciona os componentes sem verificar se tem espaço para eles.
Uma forma de "resolver" este problema, é verificar o tamanho do `Form` e caso ultrapasse, faça alguma coisa. Abaixo irei colocar o código apenas para verificar já alcançou o limite, e retornar uma mensagem caso sim. Porém, você pode fazer o que desejar.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Contador de botões para definir posição e demais propriedades
        int contador = 1;
        //Tamanho do form
        int width = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Função chamada ao click do botão
            AddNewTextBox();
        }

        public void AddNewTextBox()
        {
            //Adiciona o tamanho do firm
            width = this.Width;

            //Define posição top
            var top = contador * 25;

            //Verifica se irá ultrapassar o form
            if (top >= width)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Seu Form não tem tamanho para adicionar esse item");
                return;
            }

            //Novo textBox watts
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Top = top;
            txt.Left = 10;
            txt.Text = "Watts  " + this.contador.ToString();
            txt.Name = "watts" + contador;
            //Adiciona no Form
            this.Controls.Add(txt);

            //Novo textBox Consumo
            TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
            txt1.Top = top;
            txt1.Left = 110;
            txt1.Text = "Consumo  " + this.contador.ToString();
            txt1.Name = "consumo" + contador;
            //Adiciona no Form
            this.Controls.Add(txt1);

            //Incrementa Contador
            contador = contador + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: E quando acabar o tamanho do form? :P

Comment: @jbueno Você senta e chora. kkkk
Nem havia percebido, estou acostumado com Web que cria um `Scroll`. Vou editar a resposta

Comment: hahah tranquilo, dá pra definir o `AutoScroll` do form como true.

Comment: @jbueno Deixei uma alternativa "em branco", assim pode ser escolhido o que deseja fazer, caso isso aconteça.

Comment: Ah, é bem melhor do que estragar todo o layout do form com um scroll.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas estou com mais um probleminha... Não sei como botar o valor das novas textbox no resultado final e tambem quero saber como posso empurrar para baixo a medida que for adicionando mais txtboxes o botão que fiz para calcular o resultado e as textbox que fiz para mostrar o resultado. Se necessário, posso postar o código que fiz até agora aqui! Ty!

Comment: @Felipe Da forma que está, a resposta do jbueno é  a mais indicada, pois criará um scroll mantendo seu layout intacto. Para obter os valores, você precisará percorrer todos os textbox , algo [como isso](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/4843158) e fazer os cálculos. Bom, sem ter seu código e entender direito o que deseja, só posso ajudar com isso.

Comment: Código postado.

Comment: @Felipe Poderia postar um print de como está o seu layout?

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/d69c2b1ff08c4de0ab759da8b052c7b1.png

Comment: @Felipe Ficou meio confuso. Teria como fazer um print de como você quer que fique?

Comment: @Felipe E no final, consumo diário e mensal, irá somar todos os equipamentos?

Comment: (http://image.prntscr.com/image/72e176c5478d40c680fc02f83a07c1da.png)

Resumindo, quero que toda vez que eu adicione um novo equipamento, a area aonde está o botão de calcular e o consumo diario sejam empurrados pra baixo, para que os novos equipamentos não fiquem atrás do resultado. Mas , realmente, como você disse a resposta dele é a mais indicada, ficaria mais fácil ... Mas então o unico problema que fica é como vou calcular o resultado de cada textbox que for adicionada, porque se fosse uma quantidade certa seria mais facil... No final ele vai tirar o consumo de cada um e somar tudo.

Comment: @Felipe Utilize a resposta dele com essa daqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button/3426721#3426721

Comment: Dessa forma você irá calcular os valores ao clicar para calcular

Comment: @Felipe Mas caso queira ajuda, implemente o que mostramos agora e abra outra pergunta sobre como somar e mostrar o resultado da forma que deseja, será mais fácil para o seu entendimento.